# C++, vscode) Is there a way to change the formatting of curly braces inside parameters?

Tags: c++, format, clang, clang-format

clang formatter in vscode formats my code weird.

```cpp
onUpdate([=]() mutable {
    countText = *text + std::to_string(*count);
},
    text, count);
```

look at that, why the text, count params are there? I just want

```
onUpdate([=]() mutable {
    countText = *text + std::to_string(*count);
}, text, count);
```

this thing. my clang_format_fallback style is

```
{
  BasedOnStyle: LLVM,
  AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign,
  UseTab: Never,
  IndentWidth: 4,
  TabWidth: 4,
  AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false,
  IndentCaseLabels: false,
  ColumnLimit: 0,
  AccessModifierOffset: -4,
  NamespaceIndentation: All,
  FixNamespaceComments: false,
}
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Clang format style generator/ tester. https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/